# ASP MVC3 - Using Regular Expression Validator to find whole word

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

This is the first time I've had to use regular expressions and I'm not having any luck attempting to match with a whole word. I'm using the ASP MVC Regular Expression Validator on my view model with the following pattern:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Welcome Letter required as (Y)es or (N)o")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[|YES|YEs|Yes|yES|yEs|YeS|yeS|yes|Y|y|NO|No|nO|N|n]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Welcome Letter required as (Y)es or (N)o")] 
    [DisplayName("Welcome Letter Req")]
    public string WelcomLetterReq { get; set; }
```

This works great if I want to put in a `Y` or `N` (either lower or upper case) but anything else gives me an error message. Can someone help out w/the syntax?

Comment: You've also forgot YeS, yES, YES, yeS, yEs, etc.  Wouldn't radio buttons be an easier solution?

Comment: That's a good idea :) It would be nice to know how to do a reg expression for a whole word, though, in case anyone has a solution.

Comment: @JasonBerkan: edited per your suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not fully understand how [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) work. `|` is also a valid response based on your current logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(([yY][eE][sS])|([nN][oO])|([yY]|[nN]))$
```

live example: http://rubular.com/r/CfPJnLuHqe